# Controlling file paths in multi domain setup

Tags: multi-sites

A site responds to internal.example.com, and external.example.com.

Content editors all use internal. When Drupal generates the cached output, all images are now absolute URLs pointing to an internal domain, making them fail.

How would you handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I use the sledgehammer approach and search/replace from [template_process_html](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7):

```
function foo_process_html (&$variables)
{
  $variables["page"] = str_replace("http://internal.example.com/", "/", $variables["page"]);
}
```

You can also get fancy and use `preg_replace` if you need better control.  I typically end up needing this when I move a site from our staging server, which is a subdomain off of ours, onto a client's own domain.

If I were in your shoes, I would think about having an internal theme and an external theme, combined with one of the choose-a-theme-based-on-domain-name solutions.  Then you can add preprocess/process as needed to just the external theme.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best option is to create a *filter* to replace the URL on the fly. While you could replace it with the URL of the external domain, it would be better to replace it with a relative URI instead. There's a [dead module](http://drupal.org/project/url_replace_filter) that does this which you could adapt or take over for your needs.

The related module list is also worth exploring for other ... novel solutions.

Edit: Further information from the OP suggests that [Pathlogic](http://drupal.org/project/pathologic) might also be a good fit especially when considering the provided [use cases](http://drupal.org/node/257026#example-use-cases).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that would work. Input filters and images?

Comment: I'm assuming that your content editors are using absolute URLs in their markup in textareas. I can't think of any other situation where absolute URLs are used instead of relative ones. Or I've misunderstood your question altogether.

Comment: Images from an image-style get output with absolute urls. Yours do not?

Comment: I believe that they do in D7. But in any event, if they are inside an element which supports filters, you should be able to use another filter to replace the URLs accordingly. For this specific case, perhaps you can consider http://drupal.org/project/pathologic : see the use cases here: http://drupal.org/node/257026#example-use-cases

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to manipulate the URL's with [hook_file_url_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_url_alter/7), and another option, not file specific, could be [hook_url_outbound_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7).